# How to upload zip file through REST API Mule 4?

Tags: java, mule

I'm trying to upload zip file to the url [https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/designcenter/api-designer/projects/{projectId}/branches/master/import](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/designcenter/api-designer/projects/%7BprojectId%7D/branches/master/import). Content-Type must be application/zip, cant change to multipart/form-data. In Mule 3, a java transform class is used (com.test.FileReader) with the FileReader.class is stored in lib. It worked in Mule 3.
I tried to use ReadFile component to read test.zip and set as payload but it's not working. Any suggestion how to upload zip file in Mule 4?

```
package com.test;
 
import org.mule.transformer.*;
import org.mule.api.*;
import org.mule.api.transformer.*;
import java.io.*;
 
public class PayloadFileReader extends AbstractMessageTransformer
{
    public Object transformMessage(final MuleMessage message, final String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {
        byte[] result = null;
        try {
            result = this.readZipFile("test.zip");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        message.setPayload((Object)result);
        return message;
    }
    
    public String readFileTest(final String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception {
        final ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        final File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(path).getFile());
        final FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferReader = null;
        final StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            bufferReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (bufferReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferReader.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (bufferReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferReader.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }
    
    public byte[] readZipFile(final String path) {
        final ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        final File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(path).getFile());
        final byte[] b = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        try {
            final FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(b);
            fileInputStream.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Not Found.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e2) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

'

Comment: Could you please give more details about the error you're getting? Thank you.

Comment: @olamiral Hi. Error and solution I tried:
1. I used File read and set the response payload as the body in HTTP Request and it said "cannot upload zip file".

2. I tried customize the above Java class code so that it complies with Mule 4 standard and used Java New component with class com.test.FileReader and send the payload to the URL but it gave me error:"missing zip headers". 
I assumed my zip file is corrupted but I used the same zip file in Mule 3 and it worked fine. Hence, I assumed it must be the code in Mule 4

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your zip file corresponds to a valid API spec, in Mule 4, you don't need to use a custom java code to achieve what you want: you can read the file content using the File connector Read operation, and use an HTTP Request to upload it to Design Center using Design Center API. Your flow should look like:

[image: Design Center Upload Flow]

For the Read operation, you only need to set the file location, in the File Path operation property.

No need to set content type in the HTTP Request (Mule 4 will configure the content type automatically based on the file content loaded by the Read operation).

Comment: I tried the File read operation already but returns me 500 error saying zip file cant be uploaded but the same zip file and url I used in mule 3 but it works.

Comment: Amanda, could you please show what is the .zip content? Thank you.

Comment: I cant show fully but I created one example and this one also got error. The zip file name is test.zip and in the tes.zip contains folder named "example". In example, there are two folders named "checkup" and "error". And in checkup I saved yaml file called "checkup.yaml" while in error I saved file named "error.json"

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Java code that depends on Mule 3 classes in Mule 4. Don't bother trying to adapt the code, it is not meant to work. Their architecture are just different.

While in Mule 4 you can use plain Java code or create a module with the SDK, there is no reason to do so for this problem and it would be counterproductive. My advise it to forget the Java code and resolve the problem with pure Mule 4 components.

In this case there doesn't seem a need to actually use Java code. The File connector read operation should read the file just fine as it doesn't appear the Java code is doing anything else than reading the file into the payload.

Sending through the HTTP Request connector should be straightforward. You didn't provide any details of the error, (where is it happening, complete error message, HTTP status error code, complete flow with the HTTP request in both versions, etc) and the [API Designer REST API](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/f1e97bc6-315a-4490-82a7-23abe036327a.anypoint-platform/api-designer-experience-api/) doesn't document an `import` endpoint so it is difficult to say if the request is correctly constructed.

Comment: the url works fine in Mule 3. so it’s not the url. i know mule 4 has their own features  which is file read and I have tried it but it return me error saying zip file cant be uploaded. I used the same zip file in Mule 3 and it works. The reason why I uploaded java code so that people know the payload type i used in mule 3 and how to achieve the same result in mule 4

Comment: Understood. Please share the flow that you did try in Mule 4 and the working flow in Mule 3.

Comment: My flow is in the middle part so that's quite hard to show but in Mule 3 the flow to upload the RAML using url provide above starts from Java with transform class com.test.FileReader and then HTTP request to the URL. while in Mule 4 I put File Reader replacing the Java and same HTTP request. But error keep saying zip file cant be uploaded. I changed it to byte[] as well but still received the same error

Comment: probably the problem is in the HTTP request but it is not possible to assist without more information. Please share the File and HTTP request operations at least, in XML.